# Unable to install pandas=0.18.1 on Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-3.6

I am trying to setup a legacy project using python 3.6.13 as a constraint. Though I am running into an issue trying to install pandas version 0.18.1

The log are as below:

```
Collecting numpy==1.11.1 (from -r requirements-remote.txt (line 25))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/4c/515d7c4ac424ff38cc919f7099bf293dd064ba9a600e1e3835b3edefdb18/numpy-1.11.1.tar.gz
Collecting pandas==0.18.1 (from -r requirements-remote.txt (line 26))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/09/e66eb844daba8680ddff26335d5b4fead77f60f957678243549a8dd4830d/pandas-0.18.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qqqqq/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/Users/qqqqq/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/Users/qqqqq/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/Users/qqqqq/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/pyenv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/var/folders/zc/tjmjl2890y57f30n1yg7dg39xl_6k6/T/easy_install-zcqg452m/numpy-1.21.0rc2/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
    _CYTHON_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(min_cython_ver)
RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required.
```

Comment: Try installing an older version of pandas. The error message at the end seems dispositive as to why it refuses to install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit: `Python version >= 3.7 required`. According to the paths you’re using `3.6` (i.e. from 2016, and that will reach end-of-life at the end of the year).

This seems to come from the fact that pandas is trying to install [`numpy-1.21.0rc2`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.21.0rc2/) as a dependency, see the traceback (emphasis mine):

> File "/var/folders/zc/tjmjl2890y57f30n1yg7dg39xl_6k6/T/easy_install-zcqg452m/**numpy-1.21.0rc2**/setup.py", line 34, in

I’m not sure why pandas is doing that, but if you first install the numpy from your requirements file, pandas might consider that dependency resolved.

```sh
pip install numpy==1.11.1
pip install -r requirements-remote.txt
```

By the way, neither [numpy 1.11.1](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.11.1/) nor [pandas 0.18.1](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.18.1/) list python 3.6 as a supported python version, they both have 3.5 at most. It might still work, but maybe it could also fail due to python 3.6 being *too new* (I have no way of testing this − sorry). You could try to refresh these dependencies to the highest versions that still support python 3.6:

- [numpy 1.19.5](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.19.5/)
- [pandas 1.1.5](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.1.5/)

Comment: can't thank enough for this. saved my day and the rest of the week and the weekend and the year as well!!!